# OpenIdConnect abort workflow

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, asp.net-authorization

I implemented openId connect to an AspNetCore application.

When the user logs-in, i want to read a flag from db, and abort the login workflow if the user is locked.

The only event where i have access to the OpenId claims is `OnTokenValidated`

Is it possible to abort the "login" workflow from OpenId?

```
services
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
        // code removed for simplicity

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                IUsersRepository usersRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUsersRepository>();

                ClaimsPrincipal principal = context.Principal;
                string userId = principal.Claims.First(p => p.Type == "user_id").Value;

                var user = usersRepository.GetByExternalProviderIdentifier(userId, false);
                if(user.IsLocked == true)
                {
                    // although i redirect the user, the cookies are already created, and the user is logged-in.

                    // How can i abort the login workflow? ie. prevent the cookies from being saved
                    string redirectUrl = $"/Auth/Login?error={WebUtility.UrlEncode("Your account is locked")}";
                    context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
                }

                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: The event context should have a Handled method to end the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You may to use `Fail` method of context:

```
if(user.IsLocked == true)
{
     ...
     context.Fail("user is locked");
}
```

Comment: Tried this as well. `Fail()` will throw an exception. I simply try to redirect the user to the login page.